# How do I effectively retrieve large set of data from two differnt databases using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database

- DatabaseA
- DatabaseB

DatabaseA contains tables:

- staff
- leaveEntry

DatabaseB contains tables:

- punchingLogs
- holidaySettings
- workingHours

Table staff consists of 200+ records and leaveEntry consists of leave entry for a staff as employee id as unique field.

Table punchingLogs consists of details of punching in and out from the organization. A mininum of 2 logs will be there per employee per day.

While calculating the monthly report, I have to iterate through every single day and needs to calculate leave entries, leave types, punching timings etc.

Currently I had coded this using a bunch loops gor fetching datas day by day and then calculating attendance.I think this is not the best solution do far..So I created a class Employee and trying to update details to class members once I found the relevant staff id in the database.  The logic im using is: ill create new objects employee and add it to

```
$allstaff =array ();

$allstaff [id] = new object ();
```

Here id will ne the unique staffid from db this may be any value from 1 to 200  + . Is this a gud practice to retrieve and store data in such manner?

The newly created Employee class consists basic setter and getters:

```
class Employee{
var $empName;
var $dept;
var $cat;
var $cl;
var $hpl;
var $coff;
var $dl;
var $lop;
function __construct($name,$department,$category,$casual,$halfpay,$compoff,$duty,$losofpay){
  $this->empName=$name;
  $this->dept=$department;
  $this->cat=$category;
  $this->cl=$casual;
  $this->hpl=$halfpay;
  $this->coff=$compoff;
  $this->dl=$duty;
  $this->lop=$losofpay;
}
function  getEmployeeName(){
  return $this->empName;
}
function  getEmployeeDeptName(){
  return $this->dept;
}
function  getEmployeeCatName(){
  return $this->cat;
}
function  getEmployeeCl(){
  return $this->cl;
}
function  getEmployeeHpl(){
  return $this->hpl;
}
function  getEmployeeCoff(){
  return $this->coff;
}
 function  getEmployeeDl(){
  return $this->dl;
}
function  getEmployeeLop(){
  return $this->lop;
}
}
```

Query for staffdetails:

```
$queryStaff=mysql_query("SELECT * from `staff` WHERE `dept_id`=$dept AND `staffstatus_id`=1 ORDER BY `staffcategory_id` ASC");
```

Query for leaveEntry:

```
$leaveQ=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `leave_entry` WHERE `staff_id`='$staffUID' AND `leavedate`='$dateMake' AND `status`='1'");
```

Query for puchLogs:

```
$queryPunch=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `attendancelogs` WHERE `EmployeeCode`='$staffCode' AND `LogDate`='$dateMake' ORDER BY `LogTime` ASC");
```

Comment: I'm curious why you use two databases at all? :) You'd first need to fetch information from database A (and store it, in an array as you suggest) and then compare that information accordingly with the data in Database B.

Comment: First simple step would be only selecting the needed fields in your querys without seeing any code.

Comment: Yes that was a wrong decision from me.

Comment: @TopQuestions definitely! !., but I doubt that is there any problem if I use such a big indices for that array, ie 200 or 280. and the funniest part is : for a set of employees the employee id may be 1,4,10,66,80,168,220 etc..

Comment: @Shan can you provide some code of the class you have, and a simple of your database query.

Comment: @Alex Question updated

Comment: Fix your design. Simples.